# How to logoff all users?

Tags: c#

I'm very new to c# and I want to do a code that will logoff all users that logged to the pc.
I tried to do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process("shutdown", "/l");
```

But this didn't logged off all the users, this logged off only the user that I was running from it.
So how can I do this?

Comment: Does your program run as admin, with elevation?

Comment: Take a look here. It might be easy to convert to a c# call: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2da3e724-eddf-4df7-8e0c-3fa545c2fec0/script-to-logoff-all-user-sessions-in-windows-2008-r2?forum=winserverTS

Answer (score 0):

Use the WTSDisconnectSession() Windows API. See article here.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

class Program
{
  [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern bool WTSDisconnectSession(IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, bool bWait);

  const int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = -1;
  static readonly IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    if (!WTSDisconnectSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
         WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, false))
      throw new Win32Exception();
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code it just logs off the current user, not all users as asked.